# rolling windows defined by backward cumulative sums

Tags: pandas, rolling-computation

I have got a pandas DataFrame like this:

```
    A    B  
0   3   ...  
1   2    
2   4    
3   4    
4   1    
5   7    
6   5    
7   3
```

I would like to compute a rolling along column A summing its elements backwards until I reach at least 10. The resulting windows should be:

```
    A    B      window_indices
0   3   ...     NA
1   2           NA
2   4           NA
3   4      -->  [3,2,1]
4   1           [4,3,2,1]
5   7           [5,4,3]
6   5           [6,5]
7   3           [7,6,5]
```

Next, I want to compute some statistics on column B, something like that:

```
df.my_rolling(on='A', func='sum', threshold=10).B.mean()
```

I have got an idea: we could think of the elements of column A as seconds. Transform A in a datetime column and perform a standard rolling on it. But I don't know how to do that.

Comment: I don't think this can be easily in a vectorized manner.

Answer (score 0):

This is no able to do with rolling since the rolling window is not fixed

```
l = [[df.index[(df.A.loc[:x].iloc[::-1].cumsum()>=10).idxmax():x+1].tolist()[::-1] 
             if (df.A.loc[:x].sum()>=10) else np.nan] for x in df.A.index]
                                                               
Out[46]: 
[[nan],
 [nan],
 [nan],
 [[3, 2, 1]],
 [[4, 3, 2, 1]],
 [[5, 4, 3]],
 [[6, 5]],
 [[7, 6, 5]]]

 df['new'] = l
```